# Create Setup File

Tags: .net, deployment

I write a C# solution includes 3 projects. 2 projects use SQL database(I use linq). How to Create Setup File for my solution ? Thanks.

Comment: The tags you chose are not appropriated.

Comment: Well, I created a new project that handled the installation.

Answer (score 1):

**Just use Visual Studio Installer feature:**

```
New Project -> Other Project Type -> Setup and Deployment Visual Studio Installer
```

Comment: You are using an outdated Visual Studio Version. It does not work that way in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012 there are no longer Setup Projects. Have a look into [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) for a free alternative.